# Write a mex-File from Matlab to CUDA (CUSPARSE)

Tags: matlab, cuda

I use the sparse Martix format in Matlab to store my Matrix. But the computation will the cusparse libary do. I search for a example to connect matlab und Cusparse via a mex File.

Have anyone an idea ?

Thanks Christian

Comment: You should add more detail at least, and better, any code attempts - people will help you but generally not code things for you from scratch...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, I had a similar problem that I just figured out how to solve. I wanted to write program in C that uses CUSPARSE, compile that into a mex file, and run that in MATLAB. Here are some sources that I found that helped me out.

The MATLAB documentation has [some examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/build-cc-mex-files.html) for what your C program should look like.

Here's [the MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-mex-functions-containing-cuda-code.html) on how to set up and compile your program. Note that you have to set the path to NVCC before you can compile your code. I could never get it to work this way though.

I chose to compile the code outside of MATLAB, and I just compile the mex file with the line

```
mex myFile.cu -L/path/to/your/cuda/libs -lcusparse -lcudart
```

And that worked for me. Note that the MATLAB documentation says that your C file has to have the ".cu" suffix for this to compile properly, as well as setting the "MW_NVCC_PATH" environment variable to point to nvcc.